# Spring Boot Rest integration testing - How to analyse API coverage?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, test-coverage

I want to analyse API coverage of my spring boot rest project. (During the intergration test which endpoints are used, and related details) My strategy is like that, during the integration test;

- Run /**mappings** endpoint once, and get the total endpoint list
- By using **customtracerepository**, check the visited endpoints.
- Create a log file after all tests finished.

But I realized that predefined actuator endpoints are not working in test environment. (**SpringJUnit4ClassRunner**) Is there any way to run spring boot actuators on test environment, or do you have any other suggestion to do that? (coverage report) I aim to see missing tests in single report.